# sort only the first column and uniq

Tags: text-processing, sort

I have a list as such below:

```
1,cat  
1,dog  
2,apple  
3,human
```

I'd like an output like this:

```
1,cat,dog  
2,apple  
3,human
```

So value 1 from column 1 contains the value of cat and dog from column 2. Is that possible ?

Comment: It's quite straightforward in something like `awk` (concatenating the second column values into an array indexed by the first): why do you think you should be using `uniq` specifically?

Comment: i'm new to unix and still just ankle deep into awk so I just thought of unix -c

Comment: Are the numbers in the first column strictly ascending?

Comment: @steeldriver how would the pipeline look like ?

Comment: the question title is misleading, it has nothing to do with uniq.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that the first column is strictly ordered:

```
$ awk -F, '$1==last {printf ",%s",$2;next} NR>1{print""} {last=$1;printf "%s",$0} END{print""}' file
1,cat,dog
2,apple
3,human
```

Alternatively, allowing the input lines in any order (and output lines in no guaranteed order):

```
$ awk -F, '{a[$1]=a[$1]","$2} END{for (i in a)print i a[i]}' file
1,cat,dog
2,apple
3,human
```

Comment: @XYg If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 1):

In Perl:

```
$ perl -F',' -lane 'push @{$k{$F[0]}},@F[1..$#F]; 
                    END{$,=",";print $_,@{$k{$_}} for keys(%k)}' file 
2,apple
1,cat,dog
3,human
```

Or, for sorted output:

```
$ perl -F',' -lane 'push @{$k{$F[0]}},@F[1..$#F]; 
                    END{$,=",";print $_,@{$k{$_}} for sort keys(%k)}' file 
1,cat,dog
2,apple
3,human
```

This has the advantage of being able to deal with an arbitrary number of fields. If all your lines have 2 fields only, you can simplify to

```
perl -F',' -lane 'push @{$k{$F[0]}},$F[1]; 
                  END{$,=",";print $_,@{$k{$_}} for sort keys(%k)}' file
```